# Transformation of Random Variable from $\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R$

Tags: measure-theory, probability-distributions

Say $X\sim F$ is a random vector is $\mathbb R^n$ with $F\ll\lambda$ (where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue Measure in $\mathbb R^n$). I'm interested in the density of $Y=X^\top X$. How do I show that $$f_{Y}(y)=\int_{x^\top x=y} \frac{dF}{d\lambda}d\nu$$
where $\nu$ is the uniform distribution over the set $\{x\in\mathbb R^n|x^\top x = y\}$. Intuitively it makes perfect sense to me but I guess I'm having trouble taking the derivative of the distribution of $Y$. As in I know that
$$\mathbb P(Y \le y) = \int_{x^\top x \le y} \frac{dF}{d\lambda}d\lambda$$
but it's not very clear to me how to obtain the first equation. It looks somewhat like Green's Theorem since $\{x^\top x =y\}=\partial \{x^\top x \le y\}$ but I'm not sure if I can use that.

Comment: This is a consequence of the [coarea formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coarea_formula).

Comment: @FZan that solves it! Would you consider posting this as the solution?